# How to fix missing .env variables in vue-cli 3

Tags: vuejs2, vue-cli-3

When I try to call `.env` variables from a local `.env` file using web-ci 3.7, they are `undefined`.

If I console.log `process.env` only

```js
{
BASE_URL: "/",
NODE_ENV: "development"
}
```

are shown.

I set up an `.env` file in the project's root

This is how the env file looks like

```
VUE_APP_KEY: ******
VUE_APP_SECRET: *******
VUE_APP_TOKEN: *********
VUE_APP_BASE_URI=/api
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use `=` instead of `:`

```
VUE_APP_KEY= ******
VUE_APP_SECRET= *******
VUE_APP_TOKEN= *********
VUE_APP_BASE_URI=/api
```